# When is it necessary to allow user to cancel a transaction

Tags: mobile, ios

Working on a iOS app photo project that involves selection of your photo, editing, and a print checkout. Above just a photo process, when is it necessary to present "cancel" into the flow.

My best guess without seeing data is to present it when the user is in checkout portion of the flow (review, checkout). Any time sooner and I am stuck trying to stick a cancel button in the title bar or bottom toolbar somewhere as seen in the image below. To me, I am wondering how important it is a user needs to cancel or jump out of the process before entering checkout?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a "Cancel" button when the user is in a multi-step process. Without context to the previous step, it appears that your user came from a photo selection screen. The "Back" button goes to the previous screen and "Cancel" exits the entire process. Try to stay away from the "Cancel" label because, well, what is the user canceling? Be more obvious by simply stating what the user will cancel.

> "Cancel is mainly useful for multi-step dialogs where the user has
>   progressed past one or more pages with actions. At this time, pressing
>   the Back button will not undo these actions and it would be better if
>   the user would click Cancel." 
>   http://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/